# Como fechar o programa apertando a tecla

Tags: c#, winforms

Como posso fechar o programa apertando a tecla ESC? Mesmo que tenha uma MessageBox ou qualquer outra coisa impedindo? Tentei desta forma mas não consegui:

```
 private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
            }
        }
```

Form:

```
 public partial class Home : Form
    {
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MaximizeBox = false;
            statusID.Visible = false;
            this.KeyDown += Home_KeyDown; 
        }

        private void Home_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            aplicacaoRodando = false;
        }

        bool aplicacaoRodando = true;
        private void materialFlatButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtID.Enabled = false;
            aplicacaoRodando = true;
            try
            {
                labelworking.Visible = true;
                labelworking.Text = "Em funcionamento..";
                btnscriptshutdown.Enabled = true;
                btnTurn.Enabled = false;
                Thread t = new Thread(() =>
                    {

                        while (aplicacaoRodando)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        }

                    });

                t.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        private void Home_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
            {
                nicon.BalloonTipTitle = "HOME";
                nicon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
                nicon.Icon = new Icon(Icon, 40, 40);
                nicon.Visible = true;
                this.Hide();
            }
            else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
            {
                nicon.Visible = false;
            }
        }


        private void notifyIcon1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Visible = true;
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
        }

        private void cmssair_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            aplicacaoRodando = false;
            Close();
        }
        private void Btnscriptshutdown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtID.Enabled = true;
            aplicacaoRodando = false;
            btnTurn.Enabled = true;
            btnscriptshutdown.Enabled = false;
            labelworking.Visible = false;
        }

        private void Home_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            aplicacaoRodando = false;
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void materialSingleLineTextField1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnvalidar.Enabled = !(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtID.Text));
        }

        private void materialSingleLineTextField1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)8)
            {
                statusID.Visible = true;
                statusID.Text = "Somente números";
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                statusID.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente dessa forma:

```
public Home()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.KeyDown += Home_KeyDown;
}

private void Home_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Do [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx):

*Application.Exit()*

> Informa todas as mensagens que devem ser finalizadas e, em seguida,
>   fecha todas as janelas do aplicativo após o processamento das
>   mensagens.

Comment: Não sei porque mas não acontece nada, mas por botão, utilizando o método Close(); ele fecha normalmente.

Comment: E você está no Form certo? Quantos Forms tem o seu programa? Qual é o nome do Form que está tentando executar o código acima?

Comment: Só um, o nome é Home

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Pode testar? No exemplo eu uso Home como sendo o nome do seu Form, com base no que falou.

Comment: Não aconteceu nada também

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque o código inteiro do seu Form, por favor.

Comment: Pronto modificado

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78085/discussion-between-perozzo-and-slinidy).

Comment: Entra no chat lá para resolvermos!